# Return value of crud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-sql-database

I have simple table scripts in Azure written in javascript and node.js.

Now, if I call any of these from Windows Phone, the object parameter gets updated automatically from the return value. And thus code like this works

```
await table1.InsertAsync(val1);
MyObj val2 = new MyObj();
val2.data = val1.Id;
await table2.InsertAsync(val2);
```

However now I try to utilize this same from scheduled job in Azure: essentially chaining 2 insert calls so that latter depends on the id of the former. The id column is identity and gets created automatically.

How can I achieve this? Scheduled job is written in javascript/node.js. I have tried

```
var res = table1.insert(val1);
```

And using val1.id after the first insert, but neither works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And of course just moments after I post the question I come up with an answer.

```
table1.insert(val1, {
    success: function(res) {
        var val2 = {
            data: res.id
        }
        table2.insert(val2);
    }
});
```